# Javascript - How to update a document in couchdb?

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb

So we need to be able to update JSON objects in cloudant using javascript. Our teacher told us something about using the _rev number but I've got no clue on how to begin.

Let's say that this is the document I need to update:

```
{ 
  _id:"bla",
  _rev:"blabla",
  name:"something"
}
```

And I want to update it to this:

```
{ 
  _id:"bla",
  _rev:"blabla",
  name:"something else"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following docs: http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/api.html#revisions

Basically you need to fetch the existing document, change the fields and post it back, making sure the revision is correct. Revision is used to prevent updates of documents that have been updated since you got your copy (conflict).